# how can I pair my ERC20 token with Ethereum

Tags: ether, tokens

I am building an exchange and i just want to know how this pairing thing works. How can I pair my ERC20 token with other crypto assets like Ether and BTC?

Answer (score 0):

Just like you have paired other currencies to the assets. You make pairs in the trade engine.
Pairing is just a way to create market once the trade facilitates then transaction model comes into play.

Comment: can you please explain in detail cuz i am new into it. 
Thanks

Comment: Are you using a Trade Engine? If yes, just make the pair in the database, If not then please explain the whole scenario to me.